# power bi format chart or graph number

Tags: graph, dax, powerbi-desktop, measure

My card or graph tries to intelligently come up with the format to use for the number to display.
For example, if the scorecard says "11M" instead of 11,000,000.
How do you change this to 11,000,000?
Here is picture of scorecard and KPI chart
[image: see pic]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it!
It is under Indicator option under formatting.
It is set to Auto.
It has millions, thousands, and other options.
A hard find...